# Type annotating a function that returns a dynamic class

Tags: python, annotations, mypy, python-typing, python-pyre

I have a use-case where I have two classes: `Foo` and `Bar`.

I want to write a function that, given one of these classes, dynamically creates a new class that is a subclass of the given class. This is what I currently have:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar

class Foo:
    ...

class Bar
    ...

T = TypeVar("T")

def generate_child_class(base_class: Type[T]) -> Type[T]:
    class GeneratedClassPlaceholder(base_class):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
            super(GeneratedClassPlaceholder, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            # some additional logic unique to the subclass
            ...

    return GeneratedClassPlaceholder
```

I intend to use that function as following:

```py
FooChildClass = generate_child_class(Foo)
BarChildClass = generate_child_class(Bar)
```

However, the type-checker complains about the function: "Incompatible return type [7]: Expected `Type[Variable[T]]` but got `Type[GeneratedFixtureClass]`."

How do I correctly type-annotate this code? Could a metaclass be useful here?

Thank you!

Comment: a metaclass is of no help - it is of no help with typing in general: static typecheckers can't know what modifications metaclasses do to classes at runtime.  (I even removed the metaclass tag from the question)

Comment: However, I get a different error from mytype: it just complains that `Variable "base_class" is not valid as a type`, and I can't work around that, unless adding `# type: ignore` to the line with the class statement  (that is, I do: `class GeneratedClassPlaceHolder(...):  # type: ignore`), then I get no errors at all, and the typechecking works as expected (it accepts the derived class as a return type as you want, and will error if I change anything in the function)

Comment: Python 3.10 with mypy 0.971 here.

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno, I’m actually using pyre (https://github.com/facebook/pyre-check) rather than mypy, but there is no pyre tag in stack overflow + I assumed some of the mypy experts may be able to help resolve this…

Comment: "but there is no pyre tag in stack overflow" - now there is! (creating new tags is one of the privileges one gains with reputation points)

Comment: That said, I made some tests with `pyre`: it seems it ignores completely the creation of the new class (i.e. it simply does not  "see" that the passed class is used as base to create the new class). Trying to use `typing.cast` also has no effect on pyre response - so you will likely just have to mark the function as returning `Any`.